# Concatenating and minifying RequireJS with Grunt

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs, gruntjs

I have a project written in CoffeeScript that uses AngularJS. My vendor dependancies are installed using Bower and my file structure is like this:

```
- assets
 - js
  - app
   - model
    - *.coffee
   - factory
    - *.coffee
   ...
   - app.coffee
   - config.coffee
   - routes.cofeee
  - vendor
   - angular
   - lodash
   ...
  - dist
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. I'm trying to work out how I can use RequireJS's `r.js` to optimise my app files so that I essentially get a concatenated file all ordered nice (so vendor dependancies, my config and routes, and they my app files).
2. Integrate this into my Grunt file.

I've tried using the `r.js` optimiser but maybe I've being too silly as all it seems to do is copy my app files (minus the vendor dependancies) into the dist folder; it does, however, manage to optimise the `coffee` generated `js` files.

Has anyone got any experience with this?

Comment: Are you using `require.js` in tandem with `r.js`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out: `r.js` works by reading your `mainConfigFile` and any modules you name within your configuration, the important note here is that `r.js` only looks at the first `require`/`define` within your named modules and goes off to seek them; so, for example, I had one named module called `app`:

```
require ['config'], (cfg) ->
  require ['angular'], (A) ->
    A.module cfg.ngApp, []

    require ['routes'], () ->
      require [
        'factory/a-factory',

        'service/a-service',

        'controller/a-controller'
      ], () ->
        A.bootstrap document, [cfg.ngApp]
```

The problem here was that `r.js` never got past the first `require` statement and thus the concatenation wasn't working. When I changed this to, say (my `app.coffee`):

```
require ['config'], (cfg) ->
  require ['angular'], (A) ->
    A.module cfg.ngApp, []

    require ['bootstrap'], (bootstrap) ->
      bootstrap()
```

And my `bootstrap.coffee`:

```
define [
  'config',
  'angular',
  'routes',

  'factory/a-factory',

  'service/a-service',

  'controller/a-controller'
], (cfg, A, routes) ->
  class Bootstrap
    constructor: () ->
      routes()

      A.bootstrap document, [cfg.ngApp]
```

This meant that I only needed to define `angular` and `bootstrap` in my `r.js` configuration as `includes` and then `r.js` would do the rest, like so:

```
baseUrl: 'assets/js/app',
mainConfigFile: 'assets/js/app/config.js',
name: 'app',
include: [
  '../vendor/requirejs/require',
  'bootstrap'
],
out: 'assets/js/dist/app.js'
```

And now it all works fine! ~~It's a shame that I have to tell `r.js` to include `requirejs` though, maybe I've done something silly there?~~

**Blimey, I'm such a dingus!**

So in my HTML I was loading my concatenated script as:

```
<script src="assets/js/dist/app.js"></script>
```

When really it *should* be loaded like this:

```
<script src="assets/js/vendor/requirejs/require.js" data-main="assets/js/dist/app"></script>
```

D'oh!

Comment: Thanks for not only returning to provide an answer to your own question, but a very good one at that.

Answer (score 1):

**From r.js doc**

https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L322

Nested dependencies can be bundled in requireJS > v1.0.3

```
//Finds require() dependencies inside a require() or define call. By default
//this value is false, because those resources should be considered dynamic/runtime
//calls. However, for some optimization scenarios, it is desirable to
//include them in the build.
//Introduced in 1.0.3. Previous versions incorrectly found the nested calls
//by default.
findNestedDependencies: false,
```